# Porting VC++ inline assembler to x64 (of a __stdcall hook)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I need to port the inline assembler to be able to compile on x64.
I'm trying to get familiar with the x64 Intrinsics etc but I guess someone being into it could easily help me out.

```
void __stdcall Hook(P1, P2)
{
    __asm pushad

    static void* OriginalFunctionPointer =
        GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("Some.dll"), "[...]");

    // [...]

    __asm popad

    __asm push (P2)
    __asm push (P1)
    __asm call (OriginalFunctionPointer)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you need a hooking library like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/LibMinHook.aspx)(or [this](http://www.gamedeception.net/content/193-Cross-platform-x86-x86-64-detours) if you want a C++ API) along with a function proto, then no inline assembly is needed, in 32 or 64-bit mode. also, those pushad/popad's aren't needed when you are doing inline assembly.

```
typedef void (__stdcall*myfp)(int,int);
void __stdcall MyHook(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    static myfp TheFP = (myfp)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("Some.dll"), "[...]");

   //your extra code
   TheFP(arg1,arg2);
}
```

of course the injection of this hook needs to take place somewhere else.
for hooking classes you need to account for the hidden `this` pointer (`pDevice` in this case):

```
#define D3D8FUNC(name,...) typedef HRESULT (__stdcall * name)(__VA_ARGS__)
D3D8FUNC(D3D8SetTexture,void* pDevice, DWORD dwStage, void* pTexture);

HRESULT __stdcall D3DSetTexture(void* pDevice, DWORD dwStage, void* pTexture)
{
    LOG("[D3DSetTexture][0x%p] Device: 0x%p Stage: %u Texture: 0x%p\n",_ReturnAddress(),pDevice,dwStage,pTexture);
    return Direct3D::gpfD3D8SetTexture(pDevice,dwStage,pTexture);
}

//in the init
Direct3D::gpfD3D8SetTexture = System::VirtualFunctionHook<Direct3D::D3D8SetTexture>(Direct3D::gpDevice,61,D3DSetTexture);
```

Comment: @Necrolis: I'm doing this for __cdecl hooks, but as far as I know and experienced doesn't work for __stdcall hooks due to the stack order.

Comment: @zEh: apart from the fact you should have mentioned that, `__cdecl` hooks require a little more work as you need to manually forward the arguments using a `va_list`, if its a VA function (and you plan on calling the original), if its not, its done the exact same way as above (as the args are fixed), you just change the calling conv of your hook and the function pointer type.

Comment: The original function is a memberfunction of a class, does that change anything?

Comment: @zEh: if its a virtual method then you can do VFT hooks, and it also means it can use `__thiscall`, it also most importantly means you need to define the hidden `this` as the first arg to your hook and function proto.

Comment: @Necrolis: Yes, it's a virtual member function.

Comment: @Necrolis: System::VirtualFunctionHook? BTW I'm using EasyHook.

Comment: You should also notice that the calling conventions have changed for x64 code, see [MSDN - Overview of x64 Calling Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx). You cannot just copy the 32-bit asm code.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Thanks for pointing that out. Now I need to know if EasyHook is able of VFN/VFT hooking or anyone suggesting another library so I don't have to later find out it's not.